# regex to get datetime from string in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regex to get date time from a string in proper format. 
if string is `2/12/2013 2 : 31 AM` then i use below code to remove spaces before and after `:` to get `2/12/2013 2:31 AM`

```
$dtTime = preg_replace('/(\s+\:\s+)/', ':', $dtTime);
```

But what to do when string is `2/12/2013 2 31 AM` to get `2/12/2013 2:31 AM`?
I tried to use below code but not worked

```
$dtTime = preg_replace('/[^\/0-9](\d+\s\d+)/', ':', $dtTime)
```

Note that date may be separated by `/` or `-`

Purpose of above code is to get date and time separately from a string by:

```
    $dtime = strtotime($dtTime);
    $rtime = date('H:i:s',$dtime); // 08:50:05
    $rdate = date('Y-m-d',$dtime);
```

Comment: What are you going to do with this string next? Explode/extract data? Maybe this manipulations are excess then and it can be done other way?

Comment: after this, i'm getting date and time by `$dtime = strtotime($dtTime);
        $rtime = date('H:i:s',$dtime); 
        $rdate = date('Y-m-d',$dtime);`

Comment: Where do you get such malformed datetime? Try to solve the problem at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform:

```
$dtTime  = preg_replace("! (\d+) (: )?(\d+) (A|P)M!", " $1:$3 $4M", $dtTime);
```

It will make both lines look like "2/12/2013 2:31 AM"

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the original printed or written format, you're just going to have to be prepared to handle a wide variety of time and date formats. Look for markers widely used for one or the other (AM/PM after some sort of time, `\d{4}` is a year, int > 31 must be either a year or minute or second, / and - are usually used with dates, : usually used with times, etc.) to give a clue as to what you're seeing. Don't forget that date and time could come in either order, or only one of them. If you can't plausibly match one of a number of patterns, it will just have to fail as too ambiguous input.

**You're not going to do this with a single regexp!**

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach this a different way, match the groups of numbers individually and then reformat back into a valid date, using something like `/(\d+)|AM|PM/`

[Example here](http://regex101.com/r/pD7rL5#pcre)

Combined with `preg_match_all()`, you could do this

```
$pattern = '/(\d+)|AM|PM/';
$string = '2/12/2013 2 31 AM';

preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2     // month
        [1] => 12    // day
        [2] => 2013  // year
        [3] => 2     // hour
        [4] => 31    // minutes
        [5] => AM    // ante/post meridiem
    )
```

From that, you can format your result into anything you want

Answer (score 0):

You should use the native [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) class to interpret it and reformat/clean it up instead. It'll handle parsing a variety of input better than a regex. [This book](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming/) by the extension's author also helps in figuring out how best to handle Dates and Times in PHP.

```
$dtime = new DateTime($dtTime);
$rtime = $dtime->format('H:i:s'); // 08:50:05
$rdate = $dtime->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you're incoming format doesn't change, use `createFromFormat` to make `$dtime`

```
$dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H : i A', $dtTime);
```

Comment: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2/12/2013 2 31 AM) at position 10 (2)

Comment: Updated with potential fix